# How to change div order using bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3. My problem is to change order of some div in smaller screen.

My normal code is :

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>A</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>B</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>C</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>D</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>E</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>F</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The [output](https://www.bootply.com/lBF2ON5Mi4) is:

A  B

C  D

E  F

I want it in small (col-sm-12) screen as below

A

D

C

E

B

F

How to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Is not it working on a small device as you expected??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change HTML and use `display: flex` to `.row` and give order to `.col`

```css
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .changeOrder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .changeOrder .one {
    order: 1;
  }
  .changeOrder .two {
    order: 2;
  }
  .changeOrder .three {
    order: 3;
  }
  .changeOrder .four {
    order: 4;
  }
  .changeOrder .five {
    order: 5;
  }
  .changeOrder .six {
    order: 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row changeOrder">
  <div class="col-lg-6 one">
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 five">
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 three">
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 two">
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 four">
    <p>E</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 six">
    <p>F</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PriyankDey I don't think this a good idea even if it works ... if you want to rely on flexbox then simply upgrade to V4 of boostrap as this version is already using Flexbox and you will have many class utilities to manage the order without any CSS code : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#order

Answer (score 1):

Well,use `flex`and `order` for ordering the elements.You can change the order of its child elements according to the viewports in the media query.

```
    <div class="col-md-6 a">
             A
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 b">
             B
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 c">
             C
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 d">
             D
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 e">
             E
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 f ">
             F
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
   .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    } 

    @media screen and ( max-width: 800px) {
        .a {
            order: 1;
        }
        .b {
            order: 5;
        }
        .c {
            order: 3;
        }
        .d {
            order: 2;
        }
         .e {
            order: 4;
        }
         .f{
            order: 6;
        }
    }
```